# React - get referer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get the referrer to the current page.

I have my `props.location`, I want the referrer as well.

Very little info on that online, Any suggestions?

I saw maybe an option to use a global variable via `App` ?

Comment: `document.referer`. It has nothing to do with React

Comment: @Bikas its referrer not referer

Answer (score 13):

Here is the way which worked for me to get the referrer URL in react.

```
         var referrer = document.referrer;
         console.log("referrer url",referrer);
```

You can also use the same code in onsubmit function of react-redux